# Cypher query with case insensitive match for a collection of words

Tags: neo4j, cypher, case-insensitive

In a database for language learners, I have nodes with the label `User` and nodes with the label `Word`. Words that are proper nouns (like "English") are stored with an uppercase initial letter; other words (like "an") are stored all in lowercase.

I want to create a query containing a user and a sentence, and create relationships in the database between the user and the words in the sentence. However, word matches must be case-insensitive, to account for uppercase letters at the beginning of a sentence.

I have tried many variations on this theme, without success:

```
MATCH (u:User)
WHERE u.id = 1
WITH u
UNWIND SPLIT("An English dictionary", " ") AS word
MATCH (w:WORD)
WHERE w.form =~ word
MERGE (u)-[r:UNDERSTANDS]->(w)
RETURN u,r,w
```

How should I modify my Cypher query?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend storing both the original text and the lowercase text so you can index the property and search on it efficiently.

First do this:

```
MATCH (w:WORD) SET w.form_lower = LOWER(w.form);
```

Now create an index on it.

```
CREATE INDEX ON :WORD(form_lower);
```

Now you can use the index instead of using regular expressions.

```
MATCH (u:User) WHERE u.id = 1
WITH u
UNWIND SPLIT(LOWER("An English dictionary"), " ") AS word
MATCH (w:WORD)
WHERE w.form_lower = word
MERGE (u)-[r:UNDERSTANDS]->(w)
RETURN u, r, w;
```

Comment: i would recommend just storing everything in lower case. why would you store the same data 2 times

Comment: It's not the same. I think he wants to be able to display "English" in results, but the lowercase property helps him to match on "english" or "English."